# How to test only one benchmark function?

Tags: unit-testing, go, benchmarking

In my Go package there are several benchmark files like `map1_benchmark_test.go` and `map2_benchmark_test.go`. In every `*_benchmark_test.go` file, there is more than one benchmark function like `func BenchmarkMapTravel(b *testing.B)` and `func BenchmarkMapGet(b *testing.B)`.

Question is, how can I test just one benchmark function?

I attempted to read some manuals, and got nothing about benchmark by running `go help test`.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

> [Description of testing flags](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Description_of_testing_flags)
>
> ```
> -test.bench pattern
>     Run benchmarks matching the regular expression.
>     By default, no benchmarks run.
>
> -test.run pattern
>     Run only those tests and examples matching the regular
>     expression.
> ```
>
> For convenience, each of these `-test.X` flags of the test binary is
>   also available as the flag `-X` in '`go test`' itself.

For help,

```
$ go help testflag
```

For example,

```
go test -test.bench MapTravel
go test -test.bench MapGet
```

or

```
go test -bench MapTravel
go test -bench MapGet
```

To bypass test functions, include a `-test.run` pattern that filters out every single test. For example,

```
go test -test.bench MapTravel -test.run=thisexpressionwontmatchanytest
```

or

```
go test -bench MapTravel -run=^$
```

Comment: Only one benchmark runs, but other testing mehonds like `func TestMapGet(t *testing.T)` which are not benchmark run too. So, how to run a benchmark without any other test run?

Comment: Note that you don't need the `test.` prefix in the flags, you can just write `go test -bench MapGet -run XXX` which is a bit less wordy to type. (From the docs: for convenience, each of these `-test.X` flags of the test binary is also available as the flag `-X` in `go test` itself.)

Comment: On a native Windows command line, beware that `^` is an escape character (like \ elsewhere). Therefore it needs to be typed `-run=^^$` but easier is `-run==` (since the equals sign is not a regex special and not part of any test name).

Comment: Yes "-run=^$" is the key, if you didn't specify this, go still will run all of the tests.

Answer (score 5):

There is no flag you can provide, that will run only benchmarks (or only one benchmark). The [only flags related](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Description_of_testing_flags) to these are:

> -bench regexp
>       Run benchmarks matching the regular expression.
>       By default, no benchmarks run. To run all benchmarks,
>       use '-bench .' or '-bench=.'.
>
> -run regexp
>       Run only those tests and examples matching the regular
>       expression.

So if you want only to run one benchmark, you can do this:

```
go test -bench=nameOfYourBenchmark -run=^a
```

This will cause to run only tests that starts with `a`. And because each test should be named `Test<something>`, there will be no tests to run.

To run only benchmarks:

```
go test -bench=. -run=^a
```

Answer (score 0):

Test only **TestFuncOne**

```
$>> go test -run TestFuncOne
```

> stuff_to_test.go

```
TestFuncOne() {
}

TestFuncTwo() {
}
```